# Extracting words in quotes in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am making a shell script that will automate the install process of Arch Linux [AUR packages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux#Arch_User_Repository). I need to list all dependencies of the package (to check if they are installed), they appear like this in install script:

```
depends=('sdl' 'libvorbis' 'openal')
```

The easiest way (or the *only* idea) that I could come up with is something like this:

```
grep "depends" PKGBUILD | awk -F"'" '{print $2 "\n" $4 "\n" $6;}'
```

But the dependency count varies from package to package. So, how I output the names in quotes if the word count is varying?

Thanks in advance,

-skazhy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on for size:

```
grep "depends" PKGBUILD > /tmp/depends
. /tmp/depends

echo ${depends[@]}
```

Hey look, is that an array? Yes it is.

```
for d in "${depends[@]}" ; do
    printf '"%s"' "$d"
done
```

Note: In a real script you'd want to be more careful with the naming of the temporary file.

Comment: Why creating a temporal file whtn you have "eval"? :) See my response.

Comment: Because eval is just plain dangerous. Sourcing is less risky.

Comment: Excuse me, but in this case, with the source ("."), you are just *evaluating* the file you're reading...

Comment: Encouraging the use of a dangerous tool is a good way to wind up with your foot shot off.

Comment: Again, the source just EVALUATES all the input... So "eval" is dangerous. "source" (.) is not, because...? (actually does the same, but...? )

Comment: @Sorpigal: that's nonsense. Eval is a tool. If you learn to use it properly it's no more dangerous than any other tool. In fact, in this case "." is _more_ dangerous because you could in theory eval the wrong file if a race condition occurred and a malicious program rewrote the file between the time you create it and eval it.

Comment: I'm not saying there is any difference functionally between eval and source, I am saying "I do not teach the use of eval." But I do sometimes teach the use of source.

Comment: @Sorpigal: I think teaching someone to avoid a tool rather than teaching them to understand it is doing a disservice to the student.

Comment: I disagree. I wouldn't teach GOTO either, for similar reasons. I will not hide its existence I will only say "Don't use it. When you think you really need to, think about it twice." and leave the rest up to the student. I would never *recommend* it and certainly would not without an elaborate warning about the dangers and proper uses.

Comment: What are all the extra quotes for in the `printf` statement? This works fine: `printf '"$d"\n'` as does: `printf '"%s"' "$d"`.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: I don't know about you, but here (bash3.2.48, freebsd) the `printf '"$d"\n'`  version just prints `"$d"` (which is what I would expect: bash does not interpolate $d). You're right, though, that the latter would be simpler and clearer--and arguably a more correct usage of printf.

Comment: @Sorpigal: Oops, ignore the first version in my comment. Sorry.

Comment: I've switched out my printf statement for yours. Chalk it up to too many years of echo. You can easily teach a man to printf instead, but changing his thinking is harder.

Answer (score 4):

If the `depends` is just one line, one thing you may try is to evaluate the line in bash itself... This will lead to an array called "depends" that holds all the values. Seems tricky, but not with dynamic languages:

```
depend_line=`grep depends $PKGBUILD`
eval "${depend_line}"
echo ${depend[0]} # Will print sdl in your example
```

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid the security issues of using `eval` or sourcing a temporary file by using `declare`:

```
declare -a "$(grep "depends" PKGBUILD)"
```

This will create an array called "depends" containing "sdl", "libvorbis" and "openal" based on the example data.

Comment: +1 from me; this is what I was about to suggest in an edit of mine just to sidestep the eval/no eval question. A far better (and bashier) solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
grep "depends" PKGBUILD | perl -e "while(<>){print \"\$1\\n\" while m/'.{-}'/g;}"
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk -F"'" '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) print($i)}'`